# CakePHP 3 - Create new Validator

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Hi again :) I'd like to create a new Validating Data. When I bake my model, It generates a validation

UsersTable.php -I'm posting only part for example..

```
 public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
    {
         $validator
            ->add('id', 'valid', ['rule' => 'numeric'])
            ->allowEmpty('id', 'create');
   return $validator;
}
```

I would create another.. In it I write validations to another form.. Edit for example

```
public function validationEditUser(Validator $validator){
...
}
```

That's how I call validation?

```
<?= $this->Form->create($user,['context' => ['valitador' => 'validationEditUsers']]); ?>
```

Is there a process of inheritance among the validations that I created??

UPDATED

I will demonstrate what is currently happening.. This Validation I'm using for my Form Users/Add

```
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
    {
         $validator            
            ->requirePresence('password', 'create')
            ->notEmpty('password',"Field's empty")
            ->add('password',[
                'minLength' => [
                'rule' => ['minLength', 5],
                'last' => true,
                'message' => 'Password is low, add more characters'
                ]
            ]);
         return $validator;
}
```

Now, This valdation, I'm using for my form Users/Edit

```
public function validationEditUsers(Validator $validator){
         //Its empty 
}
```

That's the way I'm telling to the form context which validator to use

```
<?= $this->Form->create($user,['context' => ['valitador' => 'editUsers']]) ?>
```

What is happening is that message "Password is low.." (belong to "ValidationDefault") is triggered in my form Edit.. I thought that using context would make just validation using ValidationEditUsers.. Why doesn't it happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Validator naming conventions

You do not "*call*" validation in a form, you just tell the form context which validator to use (for checking required fields). The passed name should omit the `validation` part of the method name, and start lowercased, so in your case `editUser`.

```
$this->Form->create($user, [
    'context' => [
        'validator' => 'editUser'
    ]
]);
```

**http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#using-custom-validators**

The same rules apply when specifying which validator to use when marshalling request data.

```
$Table->newEntity($this->reqeust->data, [
    'validate' => 'editUser'
]);
```

**http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#validating-data-before-building-entities**

### Inheriting validation rules

And no, there is no inhertiance involved, if need/want this, you have to take care of this yourself, by invoking the necessary validation methods, something along the lines of

```
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
{
    $validator
        ->add(/* ... */);
    
    return $validator;
}

public function validationEditUser(Validator $validator)
{
    $this
        ->validationDefault($validator)
        ->add(/* ... */);
    
    return $validator;
}
```

This would make the `editUser` validator "*inherit*" the defaults rules before applying additional ones.

**Update**

As mentioned initially, the form helper doesn't do any validation whatsoever, all it uses the validator for is to check which fields are required, and then set the appropriate HTML element attributes. Actual validation happens when marshalling request data, the form helper only displays errors stored on the entity.

Please refer to the `newEntity()` example and the link above to figure how to define the validator to use for actual validation. On a side note, you have a typo in your code, it must be `validator`, not `valitador`!

Comment: So any validation created for me, I omit "validation" method name?

Comment: Ahh.. I tested but is not working, because there's some validations that are of validationDefault working where I don't want

Comment: Pardon? @ThiagoMoraes

Comment: There are validations that are inside function validationDefault working in my form User/Edit.. ok?

Comment: @ThiagoMoraes Sorry, I don't get it, are you trying to ask something anyway?